# TFS Database Server Remap Issue

Tags: tfs

I am facing an issue while Remapping Database Server into new Database Server, i am trying do from below mentioned steps:

**Steps for migration:**

Run from an elevated command prompt, in the below location:

- “C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools”

**Run the below commands to stop the services that TFS uses:**

- IISRESET /stop
- TfsServiceControl quiesce

**Run the below command to remap the TFS databases to the new location.**

TFSConfig RemapDBs /DatabaseName:Database_Server_Name;Tfs_Configuration /SQLInstances:CCMDVSQI0101,5001 /AnalysisInstance:Optional /AnalysisDatabaseName: Optional

Now the problem is that the new database server instance is connecting with 5001 port and due to security policy issue 1433 default port is not opened on new database server and the above mentioned script is not working because i am passing port number with separating "," and it understand
that after "," there will be new server after comma for ex(/SQLInstances:ServerName1,ServerName2 ) and it's not conceting with server.

Please help how can i pass the port along with SQL Instance:

Comment: Hi Veejay, any update on this issue, have you solved it after updated TFS server version  which suggested by Daniel below?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in earlier versions of TFS. It was fixed in TFS 2013 Update 4, which presumably you are not using.

You can update to TFS 2013 Update 4 then proceed normally, or follow these instructions.

> The solution was to create a SQL alias in the registry, which does not
>   contain the comma, but references the server with the portnumber.
>
> To add the alias
>
> - Open the registry editor (regedit.exe) on the server where you are
>     running the TFSConfig command
> - Navigate to
>     [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo] –
>     if the ConnectTo node does not exist, create it.
> - Add a key with the
>     alias (for example just the server name without the portnumber), and a
>     value of “DBMSSOCN,[servername],[portnumber]”
> - Run the TFSConfig
>     RemapDDs command using the alias in the SQLInstances parameter

Ref: https://peterlindberg.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/tfsconfig-remapdbs-sqlinstances-with-comma-and-portnumber/

Please note that I have not tried this solution, so proceed with caution.